# convert url to array in php with exclude

Tags: php, rest, api, continuous-integration

i have some url

```
db.test.net/num/index.php/api/get_abj?n_abj=A||B||C||D||E||F||G||H||I||J||K||L
```

i want to parse `n_abj` to array in php like

```
$n_abj = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L]
```

I was told to use Exclude, but I don't understand the method, can I give me a sample code or reference for me to learn?

Comment: Maybe it is `explode()` and not `exclude` !

Comment: [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should provide you with everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using below code:

```
$argument = $_GET['n_abj'];
$argument_array = explode('||', $argument);
```

Comment: Note that there's two pipes, so `explode('|', ..)` will give empty values.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `explode()` (not exclude). Use `$_GET['n_abj']` to get the parameter, and explode on that. The result is an array.

```
$_GET['n_abj'] = 'A||B||C||D||E||F||G||H||I||J||K||L';
$n_abj = explode('||', $_GET['n_abj']);
print_r($n_abj);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
    [7] => H
    [8] => I
    [9] => J
    [10] => K
    [11] => L
)
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/P3Q6a

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

**$_GET['n_abj']** get parameter from  url

```
$string='A||B||C||D||E||F||G||H||I||J||K||L';
$array=explode("|",$string);
$str=json_encode($array,true);
echo str_replace(',""','', $str);
```

Output

[image]